# Regex to find a lowercase letter followed by an uppercase between a HTML tag

Tags: regex, grep, textwrangler

I want to use Regular Expression in TextWrangler to find lowercase letter followed by uppercase between these HTML font-color tags. For example:

```
<font color =#0B610B> Word word wordWord </font>
<font color =#C0C0C0> Word word wordWord </font>
```

In fact, I want them to be split by a colon as:

```
<font color =#0B610B> Word word word: Word </font>
<font color =#C0C0C0> Word word word: Word </font>
```

I have used:

```
<font color =#0B610B\b[^>]*>(.*?)</font>
```

But its finds every thing between the font-color tag

I have also tried:

```
<font color =#0B610B\b[^>]*>([a-z])([A-Z])</font>
```

But it does not work.

Could anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Might this be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775419/find-lowercase-immediately-followed-by-uppercase)? The context is a bit different, but effectively the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing a positive look ahead, something like this

```
[a-z](?=[A-Z])
```

I don't have `text wrangler` but you can use this and match the word and add your `colon` and `space`. I tested this `regex` in `perl` and it looks ok.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat temp
<font color =#0B610B> Word word wordWord </font>
<font color =#C0C0C0> Word word wordWord </font>

[jaypal:~/Temp] perl -pe 's/([a-z])(?=[A-Z])/$1: /' temp
<font color =#0B610B> Word word word: Word </font>
<font color =#C0C0C0> Word word word: Word </font>
```

#### Update: I forgot I have BBEdit which is the big brother of Text Wrangler. Here is it in [action](http://cl.ly/D9q8).

#### Update2: Here is it in [action](http://cl.ly/DA1f) in Text Wrangler.

Comment: Nope, seems not in TextWtangler. I tried <font color =#0B610B>([a-z])(?=[A-Z])</font> but it did not run. Thanks.

Comment: It works in Text wrangler. See my second snap shot. Make sure you have `grep`, `case-sensitive` and `wrap around` selected.

Comment: Many thanks, Jaypal. I forgot to let you know that there are some exceptions (such as kW, PhD...). But more importantly, I only want to edit what occur between the two specific font-color tags (<font color =#0B610B> and <font color =#C0C0C0>).

Answer (score 0):

try this

`<font.*?>.*?[a-z][A-Z].*?</font>`

Comment: Thanks a lot but this does not work, either. There are other font tags in the text and it select every occurrences. I try <font color =#0B610B>.*?[a-z][A-Z].*?</font> but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
<font[^>]*>[^<>]*([a-z][A-Z])[^<>]*</font>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not find any occurrences.

Comment: It must be a textwrangler specific thing then - I checked this in in Notepad++ and in Java with your examples. Sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in one single Regex expression, but provided you can loop through it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkscript() {
    var content = document.regexForm.input.value;
//match any HTML tag (you could specify font)(not an opening tag)(lowercase)(uppercase)(not an opening tag)
    while(content.match(/(<[^>]*?>)([^<]*)([a-z])([A-Z])([^<]*)/))
    {
        content = content.replace(/(<[^>]*?>)([^<]*)([a-z])([A-Z])([^<]*)/g,"$1$2$3: $4$5");
    }
    document.regexForm.output.value = content;
}
</script>
<body>

<form name="regexForm">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="input"> 
            <font color =#0B610B> Word myWord<BR> wordWord </font>
            <font color =#C0C0C0> Word word wordWord </font>
    </textarea>
<BR>    
<input type=button value="run test regex" onClick="checkscript();return true;">
<BR><textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="output"></textarea>
</form>
```

this:

```
<font color =#0B610B> Word myWord<BR> wordWord </font>
<font color =#C0C0C0> Word word wordWord </font>
```

becomes:

```
<font color =#0B610B> Word my: Word<BR> word: Word </font>
<font color =#C0C0C0> Word word word: Word </font>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has not been marked as Answered. If you still have not found an adequate answer, you can try this:

Given the following examples, only lines 1, 2, and 3 should "match" your criteria. Line 4 should **NOT** match, since there is no "lowercase-Uppercase" combination. Line 5 should also not match because the font color (#FFFFFF) does not match what you specified (in the OP as well as follow-up comments).

```
<font color =#0B610B> Word word wordWord </font>
<font color =#C0C0C0> Word word wordWord </font>
<font color =#C0C0C0> wordWord wordWordwordWord </font>
<font color =#0B610B> word word word Word Word Word Wordword </font>
<font color =#FFFFFF> Word word wordWord </font>
```

The search term could be written like this:

```
(?<=font color =#(?:0B610B|C0C0C0)>)((?:(?!</font>|[\r\n]).)*[a-z])([A-Z])
```

The replacement term could be written like this:

```
\1: \2
```

The search term has several nested parentheses. The first, `(?<...)` finds the "" tag on the left, and then starts the search from the right side of it. The `(?:0B610B|C0C0C0)` finds either of your specified font colors (you can add more by adding more "|" pipes), and does not store them in one of the \# registers (like \1 or \2).

There are then 3 opening `(`'s. The first is a matching group, which ***will*** be matched with the `\1`. The third (skipping the 2nd for now) that looks like `(?!...)` will look that the characters just to the right of the current search pattern is NOT the closing `</font>` tag, nor is it any kind of newline character. While that condition is true, the `.` character advances the search to the next character, where it checks again to ensure that the `</font>` is not found.  It does this until it finds the `</font>` closing tag.

The reason for the 2nd `(?:...)` group is that we don't want that search result to be passed into any registers: we want the "everything between <font>...</font> tags", but actually excluding the tags.

Finally, in the replacement term, we paste the portion of the text from the right of the <font> tag, to the first occurrence of where the word is lowercase and before the same word hits an Uppercase character. Then it simply enters a colon, a space, and ends.  You may have to run this replacement multiple times for cases where a single line contain `wordWordWordWord`.