# Find Lowercase immediately followed by uppercase

Tags: regex, text, grep, textwrangler

My text is as below:

```
<font size=+2 color=#F07500><b> [ba]</font></b>
<ul><li><font color =#0B610B> Word word wordWord word.<br></font></li></ul>
<ul><li><font color =#F07500> Word word word.<br></font></li></ul>
<ul><li><font color =#0B610B> Word word word wordWord.<br></font></li></ul>
<ul><li><font color =#0B610B> WordWord.<br></font></li></ul>
<br><font color =#E41B17><b>UPPERCASE LETTERS</b></font> 
<ul><li><font color =#0B610B> Word word wordWord word.<br></font><br><font color =#E41B17><b>PhD and dataBase</b></font> </li></ul>
<font color =#0B610B> Word word word.<br></font></li></ul><dd><font color =#F07500>     »» Word wordWord word.<br></font>
```

There is a lowercase letter immediately followed by an uppercase in each of the `<font color =#0B610B>...</font>`. For example:

```
<font color =#0B610B> Word word wordWord word.<br></font>
```

I want to correct this error by splitting them as follows (i.e: adding a colon and a space between them):

```
<font color =#0B610B> Word word word: Word word.<br></font>
```

So far, I have been using:

```
(<font color =#0B610B\b[^>]*>)(.*?</font>)
```

to select each of the instances of `<font color =#0B610B>...</font>`, and it works fine in finding one instance by one instance of `<font color =#0B610B>...</font>`.

But when I use:

```
(<font color =#0B610B\b[^>]*>)(.*?[a-z])([A-Z].*?</font>)
```

it does find but selects everything between `<font color =#0B610B>...</font>`in one line regardless of other font-color tags, and replaces other unwanted instances.

I want it to find and replace error in each of this specific pair of tags: `<font color =#0B610B>...</font>`, not grabbing everything starting by `<font color =#0B610B>` and ending in `</font>`

Are there any regular expressions to solve this problem? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, regex is not a good idea for parsing HTML (if it's a once-off you might be OK).

I think this might be the reason your regex is not working.
Can you give an example of a case in which your regex fails?

One case I can think of if is there is no match (`[a-z][A-Z]`) within a matching `<font color=#0B610B></font>` pair, but there *is* in a neighbouring `<font></font>`. For example:

```
<font color=#0B610B>word word</font><font color=#000000>word wordWord</font>
```

In this case, the *only* valid match is `<font color=#0B610B>word word</font><font color=#000000>word word` and the rest of the string `Word</font>`, and so this is what the regex matches (since if it can match it will!)

I can think of a crude workaround but I wouldn't recommend it unless this task is a once-off because using regex for HTML is always prone to such errors!. This regex is also pretty inefficient. Try (untested):

```
(<font color =#0B610B\b[^>]*>)(([^<]|<(?!/font))*?[a-z])([A-Z].*?</font>)
```

It says, "look for the `<font colour=xxxx>` tag, followed by either an angle bracket `<` *not* followed by `/font`, OR anything else, and again followed by the `[a-z][A-Z]`".
So it tries to make sure that the match doesn't go over a `</font>` boundary.

Comment: Thank you very much, mathematical.coffee. I guess this will help me because it seems to find what I want but when replaced by `\1\2: \3\4`, the match changes to `<font color=#0B610B>Word word: xWord</font>`. I don't know why character **x** is added here (**x** can be any letter).

Comment: That's because there's an extra inner capturing bracket, `\3` contains a single character. Note that `\2` surrounds `\3`, so replace with `\1\2: \4`.

Comment: Superb! you have saved my day, mathematical.coffee. It now works like a charm. Thank you so much.